# What's the usage of <skip /> in Android application source strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, localizable.strings

In strings.xml file, I see something like this:

```
<skip />
<string name="recentMissed" msgid="3566738938889333307">"Buraxılmış zəng yoxdur"</string>
... 
<skip />
```

But I still see the gradle build these "skipped" lines, for example a build error:

```
app/src/main/res/values-az-rAZ/strings.xml:156: Error: "recentMissed" is translated here but not found in default locale [ExtraTranslation]
```

Is there anybody help to explain me what's the usage for this "skip" keyword in strings.xml? Thanks.

I know a simple method to fix these build error is just to remove these "skipped" lines from the source. My purpose is to learn the "skip" usage.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?